# Shibboleth IDP User Profile Change Feature?

Tags: select, user-profile, shibboleth, idp

We are planning to use the Shibboleth technology to have a SSO login feature between multiple part of the software integration. I am still a beginner in this technology, but does anybody know if it supports user profiles? For example, if the user at a specific SP change his profile, another SP are also gets this info and automatically use the userinfo related to that profile.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure in attribute-filter.xml to limit/differentiate the values to SP(s).

Create a seprate AttributeFilterPolicy in attribute-filter.xml

```
Example : differentiate with regex and required attributes to SP 
<afp:PolicyRequirementRule xsi:type="basic:AttributeRequesterRegex" regex="^((?!(mysite.com)).)*" />
```

> Assertion works like this : - IDP -> AttributeResolver(get the details
>   from DB/source by providing principle name -> Attribute filter -> SP
>   attribute mapper to get the information in Request Header.